# nginx configuration problem in nginx.conf file

Tags: node.js, nginx

I'm configuring ngnix in AWS Linux and nginx configuration file like below

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
            location = /40x.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
            location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

I think it has properly aligned. But when I check the syntax it showing below error

```
nginx: [emerg] getpwnam("nginx") failed in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:5
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

even though I have tried uninstall completely and configuring, still I'm facing same kinda issue.

Comment: Have you tried to remove the first comments on top of the file so it start with "user..."?

Comment: @Marc yes I've tried but no luck !!

Answer (score 0):

To see your username, execute following command:

```
whoami
```

To see your group name, execute following command:

```
id -g -n $whoami
```

replace user value with above commands resultant. Then check

```
nginx -t
```

you would be able to check with success